# Issue trying to make an API Post in React Native

Tags: javascript, api, async-await, navigation, bearer-token

I am trying to do an API Post with some information that I am saving in variables, using different functions.

To get this data before making the POST method, I have to get a Bearer Token also with an API Post, but this request takes some little time.

I have a button on my screen that I want to use it to make the final API Post, save the info in Firebase and navigate to the next screen, but for that I need my Token bearer. I don't know how to make my second API Post to get in time the bearer token in a variable, so I can made in a correct way my API Post final.

Maybe there is an easier way to set my bearer token with Axios, because I have to do several API Post in different screen and this token has an expire time.

The problem with my code is that after I touch the button 3 times, it works, and I can navigate to my next screen (the name of the next screen is in the response of the API Post final).

First time I touch the button it appears the next error:
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":""} was not handled by any navigator.

You need to pass the name of the screen to navigate to.

But after this, mi bearer token is set correctly and appears in mi console.

The second time I touch my button, the functions that I made to make this call async, are correctly execute sending this message to the console:
Promise Resolved:
LOG  Next step --> API POST
LOG  Data saved in DB and API Request completed

After this the bearer token appears again in my console, following with the response of the final API Post, but it doesn't navigate correctly.

The third time I touch the button it works correctly, sending the same info to the console that in the last step, but navigating to next screen.

I attached my code, changing some info for security.

```js
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import FormInput from '../../components/FormInput';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    ScrollView, 
    FlatList, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    Image,
    TextInput,
    Button
} from 'react-native';
import { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS, icons, image, functions, dummyData} from "../../constants"
import FormButton from '../../components/FormButton';
import { AuthContext } from '../../navigation/AuthProvider';

 // Variables to set new values
let user_token = '';
let nextStep = '';
//let username = '';

const myFirstScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {

    const { user} = useContext(AuthContext); 
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
   // const [user_token, setUserToken] = useState();
   //  const [nextStep, setNextStep] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  

 // Save User name and id in Firebase database
    const submitUserdata = async () => {
        firestore()
            .collection('UserData')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .set ({
                userId: user.uid,
                userName: username,  
            })
            .then ( () => {
                console.log('User NAME and ID Added!')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    };


    function getCredentialsInfo() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve (getBearerToken())
            }, 10)
        })
    }

    async function setUserDataDB() {
        const result = await getCredentialsInfo()
        console.log('Promise Resolved: ')
        console.log('Next step --> API POST')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve (onSubmitFormHandler() )
            }, 10)
        })
    };

    async function callForButton() {
        const result = await setUserDataDB()
        console.log('Data saved in DB and API Request completed')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( navigation.navigate(nextStep) )
            }, 10)
        })
    }

    //getCredentiales, client_id and client_secret wont be here in the future

const getBearerToken = () => {

    const client_id =  "xxxxxx";
    const client_secret =  "xxxxxxx";
    

    axios.post('myurl.com', 
    {client_id,
    client_secret})   
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
    //setUserToken(response.data.access_token);
        user_token = response.data.access_token;
     })   
    .catch((error) => {
       console.log('error en Get Token ' + error);   
    });
    
    }


     // API Rest POST - User Name Validation -  
    const onSubmitFormHandler =  (event) => {

        axios.post("myurl.com/2", 
        {username},
        {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user_token}`}})    
        .then(response => {
         // If request es 200
         console.log(response.data);
        // setNextStep(response.data.next_action);
         nextStep = response.data.next_action;
         console.log(response.data.next_action)})
        .catch((error) => {
         console.log('Error en POST ' + error);
         //setNextStep('myFirstScreen')
         nextStep = 'actual screen';
      });
    };

    return (
        <View style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: COLORS.white
        }}>
            <View style={{
                // marginTop: "10%",
                // marginBottom: "10%",
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                 <View style={{
                    backgroundColor: COLORS.lightGray1,
                    borderRadius: 40,
                    height: "85%",
                    width: "100%"
        }}>
            <View style={{
                width: "100%",
                paddingHorizontal: "8%",
                paddingVertical: "10%"
            }}>

            {/* Username */}
            <FormInput
                labelValue = {username}
                //onChangeText = {(userName) => username = userName}
                onChangeText = {(userName) => setUsername (userName)}
                placeholderText = "Username"
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                autoCorrect = {false}
            />

            </View>
            </View> 
            <FormButton buttonTitle='Save User Name' 
            
            //onPressIn ={() => {getToken()}}
            onPress={() => {
                // submitUserdata()
                // onSubmitFormHandler()
                // navigation.navigate(nextStep)
                callForButton()  
            }}       
            disabled={isLoading}/>
            </View>
            </View>
    );
}
export default myFirstScreen;
```

Thank you in advance! Any suggestions are welcome. I dont know if the useState() hook is making something work in a bad way.

Vadim answers works, I am having problems in the following screen, setting the username in time.

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';

import { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS, icons, images} from "../../constants"
import FormInput from '../../components/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../../components/FormButton';
import { AuthContext } from '../../navigation/AuthProvider';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import {Login} from '../Login';
import axios from 'axios';

let user_token = '';
let nextStep = '';
let username = '';
const followingScreen = ( {navigation} ) => {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext); // Funcionalidad del boton de logout

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    //const [user_token, setUserToken] = useState();

    //const [nextStep, setNextStep] = useState();

   
   //const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [document_number, setDocumentNumber] = useState();
    const [gender, setGender] = useState();
    const [last_names, setLastNames] = useState();
    const [birthdate, setBirthDate] = useState();
    const [names, setNames] = useState();
    const [order, setOrder] = useState();

    

    //     Bandera para validar que la data del usuario se guardo en Firebase
    const [userDataSent, setUserDataSent] = useState(false);


    const submitUserdata = async () => {
        firestore()
            .collection('UserData')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .update ({
                //userId: user.uid,
                //userName: username,
                userDoc: document_number,
                userGender: gender,
                userLastname: last_names,
                userDate: birthdate,
                userFirstname: names,
                userTramitnum: order
            })
            .then ( () => {
                //setUserDataSent(true)
                console.log('Se agrega nueva INFO al user ID!')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    };

    


//Obtener el token de MiiiApp

const getBearerToken = () => {

    

    //Data para credenciales
    const client_id =  "xxxxx";
    const client_secret =  "xxxx";
    
    return axios.post('myurl.com', 
    
    {client_id,client_secret})   
    .then(response => {
       console.log(response.data);
       //setUserToken(response.data.access_token);
       user_token = response.data.access_token;
     })   
    .catch((error) => {
       console.log('error en Get Token ' + error);   
    });
    
    }


    async function setUserDataDB() {
        const result = await getBearerToken()
        console.log('Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token: ')
        console.log('Next step --> Get user name')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( getSpecUserData())
            }, 10)
        })
    };

    const getSpecUserData = () => {

      
         function callUserData(documentSnapshot) {
            return documentSnapshot.get('userName'); 
        }
        firestore()
        .collection('UserData')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then(
            documentSnapshot => callUserData(documentSnapshot)
        )
        .then(callUserData => { 
            username = callUserData
            //setUsername(callUserData)
            console.log('This is my user that I have just gotten ' + username)
            
          });
          return username
        
    };

    async function getUserNameInfo() {
        const result = await setUserDataDB()
        console.log('Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token y User Name: ' + username)
        console.log('Next step --> API Call')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( onSubmitFormHandler(), submitUserdata())
            }, 10)
        })
    };

    async function callForButton() {
        const result = await getUserNameInfo()
        console.log('API Request completed')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( navigation.navigate(nextStep) )
            }, 10)
        })
    }

     // API Rest POST - Personal Data -  
const onSubmitFormHandler = async (event) => {

   
      setIsLoading(true);
                
    return axios.post("myurl2.com", 
            
             {username,
            document_number,
            gender,
            names,
            last_names,
            birthdate,
            order

             },
          
            {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user_token}`}}
            )
             .then(response => {
                 // If request es 200
                 console.log(response.data);
                 setIsLoading(false);
                 //setNextStep(response.data.next_action);
                 nextStep = response.data.next_action;
                //setUsername('');
                 setDocumentNumber('');
                 setGender('');
                 setLastNames('');
                 setBirthDate('');
                 setNames('');
                 setOrder('');
                 
                 
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.toJSON());
                setIsLoading(false);
                //setNextStep('followingScreen')
                nextStep = 'followingScreen';
             });

           };

    return (
        <View style={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: COLORS.white
        }}>
            <View style={{
                // marginTop: "10%",
                // marginBottom: "10%",
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                 <View style={{
                    backgroundColor: COLORS.lightGray1,
                    borderRadius: 40,
                    height: "85%",
                    width: "100%"
        }}>
            <View style={{
                width: "100%",
                paddingHorizontal: "8%",
                paddingVertical: "10%"
            }}>

            {/* Username */}
            {/* <FormInput
                labelValue = {username}
                onChangeText = {(userName) => setUsername (userName)}
                placeholderText = "Username"
                autoCapitalize = "none"
                autoCorrect = {false}
            /> */}
            {/* Numero de Documento */}
            <FormInput
                labelValue = {document_number}
                onChangeText = {(userDoc) => setDocumentNumber(userDoc)}
                placeholderText = "Numero de Documento"
                keyboardType = "numeric"
              
            />
              {/* Genero */}
              <FormInput
                labelValue = {gender}
                onChangeText = {(userGen) => setGender(userGen)}
                placeholderText = "Genero"
             
            />
            {/* Nombre */}
            <FormInput
                labelValue = {names}
                onChangeText = {(userFirst) => setNames (userFirst)}
                placeholderText = "Nombre"
                autoCorrect = {false}
            />

            {/* Apellido */}
            <FormInput
                labelValue = {last_names}
                onChangeText = {(userLast) => setLastNames (userLast)}
                placeholderText = "Apellido"
                autoCorrect = {false}
            />
              {/* Fecha de Nacimiento*/}
              <FormInput
                labelValue = {birthdate}
                onChangeText = {(userBirth) => setBirthDate (userBirth)}
                placeholderText = "Fecha de Nacimiento"
                keyboardType = "numeric"
            />

               {/* Numero de Tramite DNI */}
               <FormInput
                labelValue = {order}
                onChangeText = {(userTramit) => setOrder (userTramit)}
                placeholderText = "Numero de Tramite DNI"
                keyboardType = "numeric"
            />

            </View>
            </View> 
            <FormButton buttonTitle='Save User Data' 
            
            onPress={() => {
                callForButton()
            }}
            disabled={isLoading}
            />
            </View>
            </View>
    );
}
export default followingScreen;
Expand snippet
Share
Edit
Delete (1)
Flag
answe
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are awaiting `getBearerToken` but it does not seem to return anything, thus await is instantly resolved. Try adding `return` before axios to return axios promise in this method. Like this `return axios.post('myurl.com'...`.

Also you can change `await getCredentialsInfo()` to `await getBearerToken()`

Comment: It works! The thing is that in my next screen, it doesn't work the async, my 'username' is setting late, so my API Post answers with a 400. After I press again the button, it works. I added the code in the main question, can you check it please? Thanks in advance